# Finding the distribution $(_=)$ of $k$ heads when throwing a die n times and only when 4 or 1 is rolled tossing a coin.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Player $A$ throws the die $n$ times. Whenever 1 or 4 is thrown, he tosses an unbiased coin. Let $X_n$ be the random variable which counts the number of heads from the Bernoulli experiment of tossing a coin. I am trying to find the distribution $P(X_n=k)$ for every $k$, its mean and variance (giving me a hint towards the distribution would be good enough though).

- I noticed that the number of $4$'s and $1$'s could be counted using a binomial approach, so let $Y$ be a random variable which counts the number of throwing $4$ or $1$.
- Since $X$ counts the number $k$ heads I have to throw at least $k$ times $4$ or $1$.

  - Giving us $P(Y \geq k) = \sum\limits_{i = k}^n {n \choose i} {2 \over 6}^i {4 \over 6}^{n-i}$
- My next steps was thinking about how to count the number of heads.

  - The naive approach was just to multiplying $P(Y \geq k)$ with $1 \over 2$ but I can see no possibility to count heads now since I dont know whether a head or tails is flipped.
  - The next thing I came up with was combining this with binomial distribution again for counting k heads.

Something along this way: $P(X = k) =  \sum\limits_{i = k}^n {n \choose i} {2 \over 6}^i {4 \over 6}^{n-i} {n \choose k} {1 \over 2}^k {1 \over 2}^{i-k}$

I am not sure whether this is going into the right direction or not and it doesn't seem handy at all. As the next step I would try to use the binomial theorem, but I can't find a way to get this simpler along this way because I have to shift k indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$
X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,
$$

where $Y_i=1$ when if you get a head in the $i$-th trial, $Y_i=0$ otherwise. The probability that $Y_i=1$ is $$P(Y_i=1) = P(Y_i=1|1\text{ or }4\text{ appears in the die throw})P(1\text{ or }4\text{ appears in the die throw}) = \frac{1\times 2}{2\times 6}.$$  Thus $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=n/6$. Now for the variance, if you assume the trials are independent for each $i$ then $X_n$ is clearly (sum of Bernoulli's) a binomial that is,
$$
P(X_n=k) = {n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-k},
$$
for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$.
Therefore the variance is $\frac{n}{6}\times\frac{5}{6}$. If they are not independent then you need to compute the covariances depending on the problem.

Comment: It is actually not independent of the outcome of the die. Only when 4 or 1 are rolled with the die, the coin is tossed. Why do you think that the covariance is needed here?

Comment: You are correct, not exactly independent. Let me be more precise here (see edits). For the covariance: if each die throws (and subsequent coin toss if any) are independent then $Y_i$'s are independent and sum of independent Bernoulli's is a binomial but if $Y_i$'s are not independent then you have to compute the variance of $X_n$ using the sum I wrote. There you might have to take care of the covariances of $Y_i$'s.

Comment: Ok I have to admit that I am not that familiar with covariance since we haven't used it that much during lecture. I might have to look this up then. Could you write just what $P(X_n = k)$ is for more clarity? by "is a binomial" you mean is a binomial distribution? How does the binomial coefficient come in then? You wrote "P( appears in the die throw)" there seems to be missing something.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I corrected the typo and added the expression for binomial. If you have not learned about covariances then it is likely (not sure though) that $Y_i$'s are independent of each other in your problem. Best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes perfect sense now! I guess this is the answer I was looking for since the exercise scores not that high and the score is correlated to difficulty ;) I am wondering how they could not be independent actually.

Answer (score 1):

You have $Y \sim B(n,\frac{1}{3})$. Continuing the calculation in your way (which is pretty straight forward),

$P(X_n = k)$

$=  \sum\limits_{i = k}^n P(X_n = k|Y=i).P(Y=i)$

$ = \sum\limits_{i = k}^n {i \choose k} \left({1 \over 2}\right)^i \left({1 \over 2}\right)^{i-k}. {n \choose i} \left({1 \over 3}\right)^i \left({2 \over 3}\right)^{n-i}$

$ = \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n \sum\limits_{i = k}^n {i \choose k} \left({1 \over 2}\right)^i . {n \choose i} 2 ^{n-i}$

$ = \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n.{n \choose k} \sum\limits_{i = k}^n {n-k \choose i-k} 2 ^{n-2i}$

$ = \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n.{n \choose k} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{n-k} {n-k \choose j} 2 ^{n-2j-2k}$   (let $j=i-k$)

$ = \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n. 2^{n-2k}.{n \choose k} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{n-k} {n-k \choose j} \left({1 \over 4}\right) ^j$

$ = \left({1 \over 3}\right)^n. 2^{n-2k}.{n \choose k} (\frac{5}{4})^{n-k}$

$= {n \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n.5^{n-k}$

$= {n \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k.\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-k}$ (p.m.f. of a Binomial distribution)

$\Rightarrow X_n \sim B(n, \frac{1}{6})$

$\Rightarrow E[X_n] = n.\frac{1}{6}=\frac{n}{6}$ and
$ V[X_n] = n.\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}=\frac{5n}{36}$

Comment: No idea why I was downvoted... Just completed OP's computation to achieve the same result, without using linearity of expectation, indicators etc.

Comment: thanks I appreciate it and upvoted to neutrail again. can you tell me what happened here $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k} {{n-k} \choose j} {1 \over 4}^j = {n \choose k} {5 \over 4}^{n-k}$ and then what happens with ${1 \over 3}^n 2^{n-2k} {5 \over 4}^{n-k} = {1 \over 6}^n 5^{n-k} = {1 \over 6}^k {5 \over 6}^{n-k}$ some details seem to be missing for me or maybe you forget ${1 \over 6}$ for ${5^{n-k}} $

Comment: The first one is by binomial theorem $(1+x)^m=\sum_{j=0}^m {m \choose j} x^j$, here $m=n-k$ and $x=\frac{1}{4}$, s.t., you have $\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^j=(1+\frac{1}{4})^{n-k}=\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{n-k}$. The term $n \choose k$ does not come from that, it.comes from the previous line

Comment: Ok I see, for the second one I tried to write it down, but I am left with $3^{-n} 2^n 4^n 5^{n-k}$

Comment: The second term $=\frac{1}{3^n}.\frac{2^{n}}{2^{2k}}.\frac{5^{n-k}}{2^{2n-2k}}=\frac{1}{3^n}.\frac{1}{2^{n}}.5^{n-k}=\frac{1}{6^n}.5^{n-k}=(\frac{1}{6})^k.(\frac{5}{6})^{n-k}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! cool to see both ways are possible.